# Is TVP the correct way to query the database for matching a list of values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, table-valued-parameters

I am trying to use `IN` with the `WHERE` clause to try to get all the results matching those list of values.

To check this stored procedure, I tried to execute it and added in some values in this format `347, 348, 349` which throws this error:

```
Must pass parameter number 2 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'.
```

So, how do I form a query where I can ask the database for results that matches a list of values.

This is my table type

```
CREATE TYPE SampleIDType AS TABLE
(
    SampleID INT
);
GO
```

This is how I'm trying to test a simple `WHERE` query:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[LIMS_GetSampleBySampleID]
        @SampleID = 347, 348, 349

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

And the Query itself

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSampleBySampleID] 
    @SampleID   SampleIDType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Select statements for procedure LIMS_GetSampleBySampleID
    SELECT s.[LabID],
    FROM [Sample] s
    WHERE s.[SampleID] IN (SELECT SampleID from @SampleID)
END
```

Comment: You don't share the code of `[dbo].[LIMS_GetSampleBySampleID]`, but if you're trying to pass multiple values then yes use a table valued parameter. Although you can pass the values as a comma delimited string and use [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Answer (score 2):

The 'simple WHERE query' for testing should be something like:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

DECLARE @SampleID SampleIDType
INSERT INTO @SampleID values
    (347), (348), (349)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetSampleBySampleID]
        @SampleID = @SampleID

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Comment: Adding that in .NET application code, the TVP value can be passed as a `SqlDbType.Structured` parameter type with a `DataTable` (most commonly used), a `DataReader`, or `IEmumerable<SqlDataRecord>`.